# Muti Row Select sub Query

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

I have 3 queries and they work fine. There Queries are:

```
SELECT SUM(SALES)as NETSALES FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='1'GROUP BY GEOCODE
```

above query results :

```
NETSALES 
1
2 
3

 SELECT SUM(SALES)as FRESHRETURNS FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='2'GROUP BY GEOCODE
```

above query results :

```
FRESHRETURNS
1
2
3

 SELECT SUM(SALES)as SALESRETURNS FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='3'GROUP BY GEOCODE
```

above query results :

```
SALESRETURNS
1
2
3
```

is there any way to combine these statements to get the result as

```
     NETSALES   |     FRESHRETURNS      |  SALESRETURNS
 1------1-------|-----------1-----------|--------1--------
 2------2-------|-----------2-----------|--------2--------
 3------3-------|-----------2-----------|--------3--------
```

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product......

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention if you are using MS Sql Server or Oracle, I am assuming MS :)

Make use of CASE and you can basically build a matrix with the result you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
 (
  Sale int,
  DocRef varchar(1),
  GeoCode varchar(1)
 )

INSERT INTO #t(Sale, DocRef,GeoCode) VALUES(100, '1', 'A')
INSERT INTO #t(Sale, DocRef,GeoCode) VALUES(120, '1', 'A')
INSERT INTO #t(Sale, DocRef,GeoCode) VALUES(110, '2', 'B')
INSERT INTO #t(Sale, DocRef,GeoCode) VALUES(120, '2', 'B')
INSERT INTO #t(Sale, DocRef,GeoCode) VALUES(100, '3', 'C')
INSERT INTO #t(Sale, DocRef,GeoCode) VALUES(100, '3', 'C')
INSERT INTO #t(Sale, DocRef,GeoCode) VALUES(100, '3', 'A')


SELECT 
      CASE WHEN DocRef='1' THEN SUM(Sale) ELSE 0 END as NETSALES,       
      CASE WHEN DocRef='2' THEN SUM(Sale) ELSE 0 END AS FRESHRETURNS,       
      CASE WHEN DocRef='3' THEN SUM(Sale) ELSE 0 END AS SALESRETURNS
FROM       
    #t 
GROUP BY       
    GeoCode,
    DocRef

DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: Gotta learn to hit refresh, before posting an answer. Much better than using UNIONS.

Comment: This works fine but there is problem that this does not address that a geocode can all there at the same time i.e NETSALES,FRESHRETURNS,SALESRETURNS

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which database product you are using, you may need to tweak this a bit, but something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT GEOCODE, SUM(NETSALES), SUM(FRESHRETURNS), SUM(SALESRETURNS)
FROM
(
    SELECT GEOCODE, SUM(SALES)as NETSALES, 0 AS FRESHRETURNS, 0 AS SALESRETURNS FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='1'GROUP BY GEOCODE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GEOCODE, 0 AS NETSALES, SUM(SALES)as FRESHRETURNS, 0 AS SALESRETURNS FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='2'GROUP BY GEOCODE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GEOCODE, 0 AS NETSALES, 0 AS FRESHRETURNS, SUM(SALES)as SALESRETURNS FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='3'GROUP BY GEOCODE
) AS salesData
GROUP BY GEOCODE
```

Comment: This works fine but the result of this statement returns only one row with all the summed values which show use of group by clause

Comment: Added in GEOCODE to the inner / out to maintain the group by. Give it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works but I haven't tested. I'm adding a fake ID column, giving it value 'x' and joining the 3 result sets using this new ID:

```
select t.NETSALES, ta.FRESHRETURNS , tb.SALESRETURNS from 
(SELECT 'x' as ID, SUM(SALES)as NETSALES FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='1'GROUP BY GEOCODE,ID ) as t

inner join 
(SELECT 'x' as ID, SUM(SALES)as FRESHRETURNS FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='2'GROUP BY GEOCODE,ID) ta on ta.ID=t.ID

inner join 
(SELECT 'x' as ID SUM(SALES)as SALESRETURNS FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='3'GROUP BY GEOCODE,ID ) tb on tb.ID=t.ID
```

Comment: This is runs of but does not give the required results

Answer (score 0):

Probably terribly inefficient but works for me on Oracle

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(SALES) FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='1'GROUP BY GEOCODE) NETSALES,
   (SELECT SUM(SALES) FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='2'GROUP BY GEOCODE) FRESHRETURNS ,
   (SELECT SUM(SALES) FROM Sales WHERE DOCREF='3'GROUP BY GEOCODE) SALESRETURNS FROM DUAL
```